When building at expo > Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
I have an Expo application and it gives an error when I build. In the logs on the expodev site it says as follows:
UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_slider:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :react-native-community_slider:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:prepareReleaseArtProfile
> Task :react-native-community_slider:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :react-native-community_slider:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :react-native-community_slider:extractProguardFiles
> Task :react-native-community_slider:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Android Bundling failed 82561ms node_modules/expo-router/entry.js (1689 modules)
TypeError: (0 , sourceMapString_1.default) is not a function
TypeError: (0 , sourceMapString_1.default) is not a function
at Chunk.serializeToAssetsAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/serializeChunks.ts:455:24)
at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/serializeChunks.ts:621:25
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at serializeChunksAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/serializeChunks.ts:619:17)
    at graphToSerialAssetsAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/serializeChunks.ts:150:26)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/withExpoSerializers.ts:263:50
at serializer (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/src/serializer/withExpoSerializers.ts:296:12)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer._bundleDirectAsync (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:1026:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at MetroBundlerDevServer.metroLoadModuleContents (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@expo/cli/src/start/server/metro/MetroBundlerDevServer.ts:442:21)
> Task :react-native-community_slider:generateReleaseLintModel
> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:extractProguardFiles
> Task :react-native-reanimated:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
FAILURE:
Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>
Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
>
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 5m 48s
534 actionable tasks: 518 executed, 16 up-to-date
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I did ./gradlew clean, I also did ./gradlew assembleDebug, it said build successfull, but there was an error when sending the build to the expo site.

Edit: Fixed in https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/30898
How to fix it:
Just upgrade to the expo 51.0.25 to 51.0.26 on package.json, and re-install the packages
OR
run npx expo-doctor and upgrade the modules using npx expo install --check

I started having this problem this morning and I lost a few hours until I found this issue on expo opened today: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/30898
It has the same problem logs as me and you, the answer will come there soon
Same error here. Using eas online and --local.
I thought it was sentry or something I had changed to generate the current version, so I left the changes in stash and ran the command normally, same error
Its probably some setting in the expo itself

(first my english is very bad, sorry) currenty expo site used libs in cache, but apparently this lib is broke, we have to wait for an update, it is all I could find.
